# How to get XSRF token after clearing cookies

Tags: angular, spring-security, csrf-token

I am using Java Spring Security and Angular 7.
I have a POST request that I use to get my data.

In my server I have enabled CSRF with Spring security.

In my client I have configured an interceptor to get XSRF-TOKEN from each server response and put it in each request's header as X-XSRF-TOKEN in order to pass CSRF security.

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private xsrfTokenExtractor: HttpXsrfTokenExtractor) {
    }

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        if (req.url.startsWith(environment.apiUrl)) {
            // send request with credential options in order to be able to read cross-origin cookies
            req = req.clone({ withCredentials: true });

            // return XSRF-TOKEN in each request's header (anti-CSRF security)
            const headerName = 'X-XSRF-TOKEN';
            let token = this.xsrfTokenExtractor.getToken() as string;
            if (token !== null && !req.headers.has(headerName)) {
                req = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set(headerName, token) });
            }
        }
        return next.handle(req);
    }
}
```

This works like charm with one exception.

The first time I access my application (with empty cookies), the POST request fails with error code 403. And this is logical, because the first time, the XSRF-TOKEN is missing. However this request that fails, provides the XSRF-TOKEN for the next request. So after clicking F5 and refreshing the page everything works like charm from that point on. Here is the request that fails:

[image: error 403]

To be honest, I was expecting from the browser to automatically send an OPTION request to get the token first and then do the actual POST request with the token in its header. But this is not the case here. What is the best solution you would suggest for this problem?

Comment: option requests are only done for CORS requests, have you configured CORS

Comment: CORS is configured properly and works fine. Thank you for clarifying this.